# Drag multiple elements in JS

Tags: javascript, draggable

I'm new to JS so I need help to solve my problem :). I found a codepen that helped me drag one element of my website but the thing is that I would like to drag 4 elements separately. I applied the same class to all of them but it works only on the first one.

Link of the codepen : https://codepen.io/Coding-Artist/pen/zYWbYXV

I'm sure the solution is obvious to you (I would say a var or a for ?) but I'm learning and I really want to progress so if you could explain that would be perfect ! Thanks a lot

JS —

```
var draggableElem = document.querySelector(".draggable-elem");
let initialX = 0,
    initialY = 0;
let moveElement = false;
//events object
let events = {
    mouse: {
        down: "mousedown",
        move: "mousemove",
        up: "mouseup"
    },
    touch: {
        down: "touchstart",
        move: "touchmove",
        up: "touchend"
    }
};
let deviceType = "";
//Detect touch device
const isTouchDevice = () => {
    try {
        //We try to create TouchEvent (it would fail for desktops and throw error)
        document.createEvent("TouchEvent");
        deviceType = "touch";
        return true;
    } catch (e) {
        deviceType = "mouse";
        return false;
    }
};
isTouchDevice();
// start(mouse down/touch start)
draggableElem.addEventListener(events[deviceType].down, (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    //initial x and y points
    initialX = !isTouchDevice() ? e.clientX : e.touches[0].clientX;
    initialY = !isTouchDevice() ? e.clientY : e.touches[0].clientY;
    // start movement
    moveElement = true;
});
// Move
draggableElem.addEventListener(events[deviceType].move, (e) => {
    //if movement==true then set top and left to new X and y while removing any offset
    if (moveElement) {
        e.preventDefault();
        let newX = !isTouchDevice() ? e.clientX : e.touches[0].clientX;
        let newY = !isTouchDevice() ? e.clientY : e.touches[0].clientY;
        draggableElem.style.top = draggableElem.offsetTop - (initialY - newY) + "px";
        draggableElem.style.left =
            draggableElem.offsetLeft - (initialX - newX) + "px";
        initialX = newX;
        initialY = newY;
    }
});
//mouse up/touch end
draggableElem.addEventListener(
    events[deviceType].up,
    (stopMovement = (e) => {
        //stop movement
        moveElement = false;
    })
);
draggableElem.addEventListener("mouseleave", stopMovement);
document.addEventListener(events[deviceType].up, (e) => {
    moveElement = false;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

For it to work with multiple elements you should instantiate variables for each element and then add event listeners to them.

This can be done dynamically like in [this codepen fork I made](https://codepen.io/yukiqt/pen/YzvWjNK) by using `document.querySelectorAll` and a `for` loop to iterate through the elements, instantiate variables, and add event listeners to each one.

My modified code (it's not perfect but it gets the job done):

```js
let draggableElems = document.querySelectorAll("#draggable-elem");
let initialX = {},
    initialY = {};
let moveElement = {};
//events object
let events = {
    mouse: {
        down: "mousedown",
        move: "mousemove",
        up: "mouseup"
    },
    touch: {
        down: "touchstart",
        move: "touchmove",
        up: "touchend"
    }
};
let deviceType = "";
//Detect touch device
const isTouchDevice = () => {
    try {
        //We try to create TouchEvent (it would fail for desktops and throw error)
        document.createEvent("TouchEvent");
        deviceType = "touch";
        return true;
    } catch (e) {
        deviceType = "mouse";
        return false;
    }
};
isTouchDevice();
for (let i = 0; i < draggableElems.length; i++) {
    var draggableElem = draggableElems[i];
    // start(mouse down/touch start)
    draggableElem.addEventListener(events[deviceType].down, (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();
        //initial x and y points
        initialX[this] = !isTouchDevice() ? e.clientX : e.touches[0].clientX;
        initialY[this] = !isTouchDevice() ? e.clientY : e.touches[0].clientY;
        // start movement
        moveElement[this] = true;
    });
    // Move
    draggableElem.addEventListener(events[deviceType].move, (e) => {
        //if movement==true then set top and left to new X and y while removing any offset
        if (moveElement[this]) {
            var elem = e.target;
            e.preventDefault();
            let newX = !isTouchDevice() ? e.clientX : e.touches[0].clientX;
            let newY = !isTouchDevice() ? e.clientY : e.touches[0].clientY;
            elem.style.top = elem.offsetTop - (initialY[this] - newY) + "px";
            elem.style.left = elem.offsetLeft - (initialX[this] - newX) + "px";
            initialX[this] = newX;
            initialY[this] = newY;
        }
    });
    //mouse up/touch end
    draggableElem.addEventListener(
        events[deviceType].up,
        (stopMovement = (e) => {
            //stop movement
            moveElement[this] = false;
        })
    );
    draggableElem.addEventListener("mouseleave", stopMovement);
    document.addEventListener(events[deviceType].up, (e) => {
        moveElement[this] = false;
    });
}
```